# in vb.net, how do i exclude a column from being highlighted with a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview set up and I have set one of the properties to

```
.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
```

which is what I want, but the last col of the row is a button column and the button also gets highlighted with the rest of the row. I do not want the button highlighted. I have tried setting the last col's properties to read only, and others and nothing worked. I also set up a handler to listen for when the row was highlighted and then deselected the last col, but that just deselected the whole row.

Does anyone know how to un-highlight just the last column of buttons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking into OnRowSelected event and then making the last column not selected.

Comment: in vb.net I don't have onRowSelected. I do have RowStateChanged, so i tried that. When I change the state of the column I want, it changes the state of the whole row. I put grid.Rows(grid.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(4).Selected = False and the whole row became unhighlighted.

Comment: That is strange... I thought that would have worked... Have you tried setting cells 0 to 3 as selected and 4 and not selected?

Answer (score 0):

In the designer(or through code) set next properties:

```
ButtonColumn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
ButtonColumn.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
ButtonColumn.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
ButtonColumn.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
```

This will set column colors(`BackColor` and `ForeColor`) to the same color for the both states(normal and selected).
So when row became selected current column doesn't change color...